Further clarification needed on expected value of inversions of pairs in a list
The problem has been discussed here before. Although the solution involving indicator random variables is elegant, it is not an obvious technique when I first attempt to solve this problem.
The Problem:
Let $A$ be an array of $n$ distinct numbers. For any pair $(i, j)$ such that $i < j$ but $A[i] > A[j]$, we say the pair is an inversion in $A$. If each of the $n!$ permutations of the $n$ numbers has equal chance of occurring as $A$, what is the expected number of inversions?
My Initial Attempt:
We denote $E_k$ the event when $A$ has $k$ number of inversions. Naturally, we look at the maximum and minimum number of inversions. If the sequence is in ascending order, there are no inversions, and $\mathbb{P}(E_0) = \frac{1}{n!}$. Moreover, if the sequence is in descending order, all pairs produce inversion, so $k = N = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(E_N) = \frac{1}{n!}$. By the definition of expected value,
$$\mathbb{E}(\text{# inversions in $A$}) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}k \cdot \mathbb{P}(E_k)$$
$$= \sum_{k=0}^{N}k \cdot \frac{\text{#}E_k}{n!}$$
How do I complete the proof from here?

After some thought, I did observe a symmetry in the $\text{#}E_{k}$, i.e., number of events (or sequences) with $k$ inversions in $A$. To do this,we represent $A$ as the sequence $(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)$.
If we start with the ascending sequence ($k=0$), and we swap any adjacent elements $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ once, then we have exactly one inversion ($k = 1$). So, there are $n-1$ such sequences (because there are $n-1$ ways to swap any adjacent elements once). Similarly, when we swap any adjacent elements twice, we have $k = 2$ with $\text{#}E_{2} = n-2$. In general,for $m \leq n$, $$\text{#}E_m = n-m$$
If we start with the descending sequence ($k=N$), and we swap any adjacent elements $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ once, then we have exactly $N-1$ inversions with $\text{#}E_{N-1} = n-1$. Following the same logic, for $0 \leq m \leq N$, $$\text{#}E_{N-m} = n-m$$.
Therefore,
$$\text{#}E_m = \text{#}E_{N-m}$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(E_m) = \mathbb{P}(E_{N-m})$$
I believe from this result, together with the fact that $0 \leq \mathbb{E}(\text{#inversions in $A$}) \leq N \Rightarrow (N+0)/2 \Rightarrow \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$. But I am not sure if this final step valid...

To your last sentence, yes, it is valid. Since $P(E_m)=P(E_{N-m})$, you get $\sum_{k=0}^N kP(E_k)=\sum_{k=0}^N kP(E_{N-k})=\sum_{k=0}^N (N-k)P(E_k)$ (last step reverses order of sum). The average of the two equal summations $\sum_{k=0}^N kP(E_k)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^N (N-k)P(E_k)$ is also a valid expression for the expected value, but this average is just $\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{N}2P(E_k)$. Since $\sum P(E_k)=1$, the result follows.
